# Implementing recurrence relation for an integral

Tags: special-functions, recursion

I would like to implement the following recurrence relation,
$$I_{n+1}=-\log(2)I_n-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\frac{n!\zeta(k+1)}{(n-k)!}I_{n-k}$$
with initial conditions,
$$I_0=\frac{\pi}{2},\quad I_1=-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)$$
This comes from [my work on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4751787/1141581), and I am looking to add the first few values of the integral in my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Int[0] := Pi/2
Int[1] := -(Pi/2) Log[2]
Int[n_Integer] /; n >= 2 := Int[n] = Simplify[ -Log[2] Int[n - 1] -   
  Sum[(-1)^k (1 - 1/2^k) Factorial[n - 1] Zeta[k + 1] Int[n 
    - 1 - k]/Factorial[n - 1 - k], {k, n - 1}]]
```

We have exploited so called memoization to memorize previous values and avoid inefficient recursive calling of `Int[n]`. Then it is recommended to use `Simplify` instead of `FullSimplify` for fast performance.

```
Int[5]
```

> ```
> -(1/96) Pi (19 Pi^4 Log[2] + 
> 20 Pi^2 (2 Log[2]^3 + 3 Zeta[3]) + 
> 24 (2 Log[2]^5 + 18 Log[2]^2 Zeta[3] + Log[8] Log[16] Zeta[3] + 
>  45 Zeta[5]))
> ```

Anyway one can use later `FullSimplify`

```
FullSimplify[Int[5]]
```

> ```
> -(1/96) Pi (19 Pi^4 Log[2] + 40 Pi^2 Log[2]^3 + 
> 48 Log[2]^5 + 60 (Pi^2 + 12 Log[2]^2) Zeta[3] + 1080 Zeta[5])
> ```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: You are welcome. Perhaps it would be useful if we rearrange complicated expressions for larger `n`, you can compare e.g.  `FullSimplify[Int[7]]` and e.g. `Collect[Int[7], Table[Zeta[2 k + 1], {k, 3}], FullSimplify]`

Comment: Is there a way I can distribute a constant? For example I am evaluating $I_2$ and I get,
$$\frac{1}{24}\left(\pi^3+12\pi\log(2)\right)$$
but I want,
$$\frac{\pi^3}{24}+\frac{\pi\log(2)}{2}$$

Comment: This example isn't clarifying what you are really looking for, nevertheless you can use e.g. `Expand[Int[2]]` but I guess your expectatins might be different since various powers of `Log[2]` are also involved.

Comment: Anyway you can also collect appropriately terms with `Pi` something like `Collect[Int[7], 
 Flatten@Prepend[{Pi}, Table[Zeta[2 k + 1], {k, 3}]], FullSimplify]`

Comment: The example distributes the $1/24$ into the brackets, and the Expand function (as far as I can tell) does exactly that. Thank you again.